# Error with UITableViewController subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am completely new to Xcode and ios developing at all.

I just want to create a tableViewController so In my storyboard I moved a Table View Controller into the canvas and then I created with File->New a new Objective-C class and as subclass I selected from the subclass `UITableViewController`

Now when I try to build the project it gives me 2 warnings and one error.
The error says: `No visible @interface for 'UIPageViewController' declares the selector 'initWithStyle:'`

I am pretty sure it's my error but I don't know how to solve it. I just wanna create the TableViewController in the storyboard but I cannot because of this error.

Steps:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Generated Files!
.h

```
//
//  ThisGonnaCrashController.h
//  CrashTest
//
//  Created by Jakub Racek on 09/02/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ngneers. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThisGonnaCrashController : UITableViewController

@end
```

.m

```
//
//  ThisGonnaCrashController.m
//  CrashTest
//
//  Created by Jakub Racek on 09/02/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ngneers. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThisGonnaCrashController.h"

@interface ThisGonnaCrashController ()

@end

@implementation ThisGonnaCrashController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

Comment: You need to tell us exactly everything you did.  You haven't, because the error you're getting wouldn't possible happen if you had done everything exactly as you stated.

Comment: I get the error even I start new project, press cmd+N, create Objective-C class where name is for example TestTableController and subclass is UITableViewController. Then I press next and when the file is created I click on the Run icon. Then I get the error.

Comment: By the way, I just found that the .h file has an error as well. It says: ```Cannot find interface declaration for 'UITableViewController', superclass of 'TestTableController'; did you mean 'UIPageViewController'?```

Comment: What are you selecting when you start a new project?  Blank project?  Singleview?

Comment: I tried so far Blank application and Singleview, both gives me the error. Is it something xcode shouldn't do? I cannot say as I am new to objective-c and I am not sure if xcode generates the file in right format for me :/ I am gonna paste the files in the question

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of every single step of the process and edit them into the original post?  From before you've clicked New Project to after the error shows up

Comment: Ok, I've added the pictures

Comment: Ok, I also added the .m and .h files into the question....

Comment: Try cleaning and building the project.

Comment: I tried the cmd+option+shift+k cleaning, restarting xcode, manually removing ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ..... nothing helped. When you follow the steps exactly as I did, does it work for you?

Comment: Just reinstalled xcode.. Still same problem, I wouldn't say it has something to do with xcode itself..

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. Your code actually looks OK.

Comment: I really don't know what happened but I've removed ~/Library/Developer/Xcode folder, removed xcode using TrashMe and installed again and I don't have the error anymore.